# 404 error in Laravel 6 , changing .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, laravel-6

I'm totally new in deploying project on server. I am facing some issues. Could not solve it.
My project path is
**/home/office_user/htdocs/projects/admin**
inside
**/home/office_user/htdocs/furusato** -> there are some other project running.
inside **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
DocumentRoot /home/office_user/htdocs
ErrorLog /home/office_user/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/office_user/logs/access.log combined
<Directory /home/office_user/htdocs>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
```

and /home/office_user/htdocs/furusatoadmin/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    
    # RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301] ココはコメントにする
    
    # 以下は追記部分 ----------------------
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /admin/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase  /admin
    # ココまで ---------------------------- 
    
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

when i tried to access

**ip/admin/public/index.php**

> 404 error

and

If I try to access **ip/admin/**
it is showing

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

Please help me find out the solution.
I tried a lot of different things but nothing is working.

Comment: The configuration you shared says `DocumentRoot /home/office_user/htdocs` which is different to `/htdocs/projects/admin` you are mentioning. Can you share the correct site configuration (or write one if it doesn't exist)?

Comment: Sorry for this mistake. i edited my post. Thank you for noticing this.

Comment: Personally I would opt for a solution of setting up a second virtual host for your admin pages and hosting them in a subdomain e.g. `admin.example.com`. This new virtual host (which will be a separate site configuration) would have the root directory be `/home/office_user/htdocs/projects/admin\public`. If you fiddle around with your session cookie parameters and share the same database for both projects you can in theory also share the session